# WPF Binding TextBox and DataRow in code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datarow

I want to bind TextBox and column of datarow but doesn't work.
My code:

```
// Member is a DataRow
for(int i=0;i<Member.Table.Count;++i)
{
  TextBox textbox = TextBox();
  textbox.Text = Member.Field<string>(i);
  Binding binding = new Binding(Member.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName);
  binding.Source = Member;
  binding.Path = new PropertyPath(Member.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName);
  binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
  binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
  textbox.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
}
```

Any idea?
Thinks

Comment: Why are you doing this in code instead of xaml?

Comment: I have written a small piece of code. But my textbox appears well in my window ...

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? Are there errors? Does the textbox not display? Does the data not show up in the textbox?  I'm guessing the problem is that the context of the binding disappears once you leave that piece of code (i.e., Member.Table ceases to exist in the context of the running XAML).

Comment: I can't doing this code in XAML because the number of columns in the DataRow may be different.
My loop is more complicated than that normally. After creating and binding my textbox I added to a grid.

My DataContext is correct and Member is an instance variable.

There is no error. All my textbox displays correctly

Comment: My code for the binding textbox and DataRow is correct?

Answer (score 1):

you are creating the `textbox` in your code, but never showing it anywhere so it may be working but you will never see the results.

Comment: when you run `TextBox textbox = TextBox();` you are creating a new instance of a TextBox object that will not exist past the end of the for loop.  Another point is that without as many textboxes as rows in your table, only the last row would show in a single textbox that may exist on your form.